# How to make the ChannelOutboundHandler.write() method to be asynchronous？

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty

My project uses the Java Netty framework to transfer messages. The application is both a client and a server. When we send a message to the remote server, we want to do some processing of this message. I use `ChannelOutboundHandler.write()` in my project to achieve this purpose:

```java
public class MyOutBoundHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
        process((ByteBuf) msg);  // do some processing of this message
        ctx.write(msg, promise);
    }
}
```

I found a problem that when the `process((ByteBuf) msg)` method throws an exception, it will cause blocking, and the next method `ctx.write(msg, promise)` will not be executed. So how to make them asynchronous cause I hope the `process((ByteBuf) msg)` will not affect the writing of messages to the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

If 'ctx.write(msg, promise)' does not rely on the result of the 'process((ByteBuf) msg)', you can just wrap the 'process((ByteBuf) msg)' in a runnable task and submit the task to the ThreadPool.

Answer (score 0):

> found a problem that when the process((ByteBuf) msg) method throws an exception, it will cause blocking, and the next method ctx.write(msg, promise) will not be executed

Unless you executing blocking code, netty will not block.

Behavior you are explaining is not blocking, it is just how control flow in java works. If an exception is thrown, none of the subsequent code will be executed unless you explicitly catch and resume.

Ideally, in your case, you want to add a try-catch block around the call to `process()` and if it fails, fail the promise using `promise.tryFailure()`

Answer (score 0):

you can just add a **listener** for the **ChannelPromise** before **process method** was called。

refer to the following code here :

```
   
        promise.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                Throwable cause = future.cause();
                if (cause != null) {

                    //process happed exception will be here and you can call ctx.write(msg) 
                    //to keep spreading forward the write event in the pipeline
                    ctx.write(msg);
                } else {
                    // when msg has been write to socket successfully, netty will notify here!!

                }
            }
        });


        process(msg);
```